# Bourbaki Set theory Chapter 1 Exercise 4

Tags: logic

For some time i am triying to solve this problem in the book set theory by nicolas bourbaki:
Let $A$ be a term or a relation in a theory, and let $B$ be an assembly in the theory.
Show that $AB$ is neither a term nor a relation in the theory.( Hint: use induction on the number of signs in $A$).
I tried to use well ordering(finding a "smallest" counterexample) and straight up induction but did not get a result with which i was statisfied.
Maybe one of you guys can help me with it.

Kind regards

Comment: What did you come up with when you tried?

Comment: So this is my attempt: 
Let A be a relation/term in a theory then there is a formative construction in which A appears. Let $A_1 .... A_n$ be a f.c. in which A appears. I shall show step by step that if $A_t$ is a relation/term then $A_t B$ is neither a term nor a relation. 
Suppose that this hase been shown for $A_1....A_{i-1}$ i shall show it for $A_i$.

Comment: If $A_i$ is a letter $A_i B$ is neither a letter nor begins with other signs, hence it is not a relation nor a term.
If $A_i$ is preceeded in the construction by a relation $A_j$ such that $A_i$ is $ \lnot A_j$. Consequently $A_i B$ is not a relation or a term. Suppose otherwise. If $A_i B$ is a term or a relation, $A_i B $ has to be identical to $\lnot C$ for a relation $C$ hence $C$ is identical to $A_j B$ which is a contradiction since $A_j B$ is not a relation or term.

Comment: If $A_i$ is $\lor A_j A_k$ for relations $A_j$,$A_k$ which preceed $A_i$ in the construction $A_i B$ is not a relation/term. Suppose otherwise. Suppose $A_i B$ is a relation or a term, then $A_iB$ is identical to $lorA_j A_k B$, consequently it is identical to $\orC_l C_p$ for some relations $C_l$,$C_p$. Suppose $C_l$ is not identical to $A_j$, then either $C_l$ is identical to $A_j P$ for an assembly $P$ or $A_j$ is identical to $C_l G$, for assemblies P,G. Which in both cases is a contradiction. Hence $C_l$ is identical to $A_j$. Then $C_p$ is identical to $A_k B$. A contradiction.

Comment: If $A_i$ is $\tau _x (C)$ for a relation C, which preceeds $A_i$ in the construction, then $A_i B$ again is not a relation or a term. Again suppose otherwise. Then $A_i B$ is identical to $\tau _y(D)$. Suppose $y$ is identical to $x$.Since $x$ does not appear in $B$ because $x$ does not appear in $\tau _x(D)$ ,$\tau_y(C)B$ is identical to $\tau_x (CB)$. Consequently $D$ is identical to $CB$ a contradiction.

Comment: If $y$ is not identical to $x$ and since $y$ does not appear in $\tau_x(C)$ nor in $B$,
$\tau_x(C) B$ is identical to $\tau _y(((y|x)C)B)$. Consequently $D$ is identical to$((y|x)C)B$ a contradiction.

Comment: If $A_i$ is $sA_{j_1}...A_{j_m}$ for terms which perceed $A_i$ in the construction and a specific sign of weight $m$. $A_i B$ again can not be a relation nor a term. Suppose otherwise again, then $A_i B $ is identical to $s' A'_{k_1}.....A'_{k_l}$
Since they are identical, the specific signs have to be identical, hence they have the same weight. Which means $s A'_{k_1}.....A'_{k_m}$ is identical to $sA_{j_1}.....A_{j_m}B$ Suppose that there exists an index $i$ sucht that $A_{j_i}$ is not identical to $A'_{k_i}$

Comment: And consequently this is a contradiction because if there is then there is a smallest one but then either one of them starts with the other and this yields a contradiction like in the or case.

Comment: But then $A'_{k_m}$ is identical to $A_{j_m}B$ a contradiction. 

@SteveKass do you see any major mistake in this attempt ?

Comment: I’m afraid this is pretty much outside my area of expertise. I didn’t realize the depth of the notation when I first commented. :(

Comment: no problem steve :) 
i went through it alot now and i think that the only part where i messed up(did not show enough) was a $\tau$ part and i corrected it now.
But thanks a lot for even commenting so that i could went through it again(by writing it down here) which cleared out my mind :)